# Fedora 17: plugged in iphone, but nothing happens

Tags: fedora, mount, iphone

I upgraded to fedora 17 from a fresh install. On f16, I had an issue mounting when they had the issue with the lockdown, but I was able to resolve that. Seems like a different mounting issue is occurring, although this time, no error messages even pop up to give me an indication on where to begin. I believe I have all the necessary libraries (ifuse, gtkpod, libimobiledevice, gfvs, etc..)

relevant info from `dmesg`:

```
[  374.543085] fuse init (API version 7.18)
[  374.577633] SELinux: initialized (dev fuse, type fuse), uses genfs_contexts
[  374.628339] SELinux: initialized (dev fusectl, type fusectl), uses genfs_contexts
[  387.773718] SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
[  451.292158] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[  451.409558] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=129c
[  451.409572] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  451.409583] usb 1-4: Product: iPhone
[  451.409591] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[  451.409598] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: c8f6b8e7a41a3b70c5f4ad2959e712a6b230631f
[  452.066930] ipheth 1-4:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
[  452.068094] usbcore: registered new interface driver ipheth
[  452.147433] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  558.884407] SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
[ 1651.445841] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1651.458101] ipheth 1-4:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet now disconnected
[ 1655.071163] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[ 1655.190166] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=129c
[ 1655.190180] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1655.190191] usb 1-4: Product: iPhone
[ 1655.190198] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[ 1655.190206] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: c8f6b8e7a41a3b70c5f4ad2959e712a6b230631f
[ 1655.303304] ipheth 1-4:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
[ 1655.459916] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:129c Apple, Inc.
```

---

> **Solution:**
>
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815491#c2
>
> Per the bugzilla for this issue, there is a comment saying that the
>   1.0.8-2.fc17 has the fix in it. However, until this fix is pushed, you can fix it by editing: `lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules`
>
> and changing: `OWNER="usbmux"` to `OWNER="usbmuxd"`
>
> and this solved it for me.

Comment: Don't crosspost: you posted the same question in [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/431039/fedora-17-plugged-in-iphone-but-nothing-happens).

Comment: @Renan I felt this was a more appropriate forum. I did already go back a delete it though...

Comment: After you plug in the device does `dmesg` indicate that the system 'sees' the device?

Comment: @Tim It appears so-- for brevity sake, I tried to omit what didn't look related.

Comment: “nothing happens” like stated in your question is wrong, your dmesg output clearly shows that your iPhone has been detected.

Comment: @Marco Semantics I guess, but I'm sure you were able to piece together that I meant I'm unable to mount the device and no error messages appeared in a manner I'm equipped to find.

Comment: @OnResolve Your intended end result is you want to mount the storage?

Comment: @Tim Yes, sorry I didn't make it more clear.I'm a not as strong in *nix environment as I'd like to be--but I was used to plugging my phone in and having it mounted automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the usbmuxd package, details see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815491

Comment: comment #2 had the solution; I've updated my question to contain the details of the fix.  Great find!

Answer (score 2):

When the system is not verbose about attaching a new USB device, you can always check the output of `dmesg` to see if the attached new USB device being detected.

For accessing the storage on an IOS device, you will need the gtkpod-aac package (That is it's name in Debian/Ubuntu), other distros may use a different name.

See this TechRepublic article, has some good hints: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/how-do-i-connect-an-apple-ipod-to-an-ubuntu-linux-pc/217

Comment: seeing the result of my dmesg, it appear that it's "connected". Taking it a step further I how would I go about mounting it?

Comment: Check out the updates in my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, i have gtkpod already installed :(